# unicornの.socketファイルがうまく生成されません

Tags: ruby, nginx, unicorn

`sinatra`+`unicorn`+`nginx`での環境構築に挑戦しています。
しかし、`unicorn`を立ち上げるところでエラーがでて困っています。
どうかお力を貸してください。

環境

- mac osx

  - vagrant
  - centos 6.6

エラー内容

```
FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=/var/www/html/unicorn/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
/var/www/html/unicorn/vendor/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:158:in `initialize': Operation not permitted - "/var/www/html/unicorn/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock" (Errno::EPERM)
```

`unicorn.rb`は以下のようになっています。

```
@dir = File.expand_path("/var/www/html/unicorn", __FILE__)

worker_processes 2
working_directory @dir

timeout 300
listen "/var/www/html/unicorn/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 1024

pid "#{@dir}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "#{@dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{@dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

なお、`listen`を`3000`などにするとうまく起動します。

この`.socket`というファイルは勝手に作られるのか、それとも自分で用意して読み込ませるのかがわからないのですが、とりあえず`/var/www/html/unicorn/tmp/sockets/`のパーミッションは`777`にしてみましたが、結果は同じでした。

ググっても`listen`を絶対パスにしろと書いてある物しか見つけられなかったので、教えてください。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: unicornのタグを追加しました。

Comment: 先程回答しましたが、的外れかもしれません。よろしければ「stat /var/www/html/unicorn/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock」の実行結果を教えていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

> listenを3000などにするとうまく起動します。

unicorn が使用するポート番号はデフォルトで 8080 だそうですが、もしかして別のサーバプロセスが 8080 番ポートを使用していたりはしませんか？ `netstat` や `lsof` コマンドなどを使用して確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。具体的には以下を root 権限で実行します。

- netstat

  # netstat -tlnp | grep ':8080'
- lsof

  # lsof -i TCP:8080

Answer (score 1):

まず[英語版の同内容の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16388342)からの引用ですが、unixドメインソケットはVagrantの共有ディレクトリには置けません。もしかして該当のディレクトリは共有ディレクトリではないですか？

また、unicornの場合はどうか知りませんがNodejsではUnixドメインソケットでlistenした場合sockが自動では消えてくれない問題がありました。もちろんゴミが残ってたらlistenできないのでもし同名のソケットが残っている場合はunlinkしてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/`内にある設定ファイル側で記述した`.sock`のパスと`unicorn.rb`内の`listen`で指定したパスは同じものにする必要があります。

```
# 'unicorn'の部分はプロクシパス
upstream unicorn {
    # ここのパスを'unicorn.rb'と合わせる
    server unix:/var/www/html/unicorn/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    location / {
        # upstreamで指定した名前と合わせる
        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    }
}
```

のような設定になっていますか？

以下の記事は`sinatra`用ですが、`unicorn`と`nginx`の説明の部分は参考になるかと思います。

[Sinatra Recipes - Deployment - Nginx Proxied To Unicorn](http://sinatra.ruby.iijgio.com/p/deployment/nginx_proxied_to_unicorn)